# Accessing Advantage Management Utility values for feedback

Tags: sql, delphi, advantage-database-server

In our report generation application, there's some pretty hefty queries that take a considerable amount of time to run.  User feedback up until this point has been basically zip while the server chugs away at their request.  I noticed that there's a tab on the ADA Management Utility that shows progress on the query both as percent complete and estimated seconds remaining.  I tried digging through the tables to see if I could find any of this information exposed, as well as picking through the limited documentation available for ADBS and couldn't find anything useful.

Does anyone know if there's a way I can cull this information outside ADA to provide some needed user feedback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ADA is getting that information from the [sp_GetSQLStatements system procedure](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage9.1/advantage_sql/system_procedures/procedures/sp_getsqlstatements.htm).

However, the traditional way of providing progress information for any operation is through a [callback function](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage9.1/advantage_concepts/advantage_functionality/callback_functionality.htm).

Comment: This is a great link.  I'm going to toy around with it today.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an answer to the question but might be useful in helping reduce the time it takes to run the queries in the report.  You may have already done this and made it as optimized as it gets.  But if not, you might look at the query plan within Advantage Data Architect to check for optimization issues. In the query window where you run a query, you can choose `Show Plan` from the `SQL` menu (or click the button in the toolbar).  This will display the execution plan with optimization information that might help identify missing indexes.

Another tool that might be helpful in identifying unoptimized queries is through [query logging](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?Key=42&ID=45).  It is also [discussed here](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/WebHelp/Advantage9.1/advantage_sql/sql_functionality/sql_query_logging.htm).

Comment: This logging information will definitely come in handy.  I'm new to ADBS, and have been having a difficult time getting feedback for myself on some of these queries.  Now I know where to look to optimize things better.  Thanks.